# How does variance change when a mean observation is removed?

Tags: statistics, mean, variance

How long is your morning commute? The displayed are times (minutes) of your morning commute during the first two weeks of the fall term.

43
62
49
47
95
53
54
48
42
47

You are also given that  ∑10i=1 xi=540 and the variance of morning commute is 241.1 minutes^2. Now, an observation equal to the mean is to be removed. As a result, the variance would:

a) increase.

b) decrease.

c) be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to the sample variance, which is

[image]

Then, the contribution of the sample mean towards sample variance is effectively 0. If you remove an observation that is the mean, then sum(Y-Ybar)^2 is unchanged while n decrease.

This makes the sample variance higher.

You can visualize this with the following R code:

```
f2=function(x){
 obs = rpois(100,x)
 c(var(obs),var(obs[obs!=x]))
 }
res = t(sapply(1:100,f2))
colnames(res) = c("Variance","Variance_without_mean")
plot(res)
abline(a=0,b=1)
```